# JavaScript ES6 project and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have been asked to work on a project and to use ES6 when coding the JavaScript on the project.

The project also needs to use React.

I've been searching for the answer to the following question on google but I haven't been able for get it answered so I hope I am allowed to ask this question here.

My question is ... If I need to use ES6 and React on this project, does that mean that I cannot use jQuery?

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to use jQuery?

Comment: Both jQuery and ES6 are JavaScript. I don’t know what you can use or can’t use. Why don’t you ask those who asked you to do it? I just know that if you’re going to use ES6, you don’t really need jQuery (I mean even less than with a lower edition than ES6).

Comment: You can use Jquery it is just a javascript library same as react.

Comment: You probably don't even _want_ to use jQuery if already using React...

Comment: Basically they want to project written in ES6 ... can jQuery code be written in ES6?

Comment: @MarkcceEros Of course it can... why wouldn't it be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery along with React and ES6. At the end of the day, it's all JavaScript. However, if you structure your code correctly with React components, you should not need to use jQuery selectors to make any changes to the DOM.

Comment: Nitpick: ECMAScript is the *standard* that JavaScript *implements*.